# Can't pull text from txt file and output into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't really know much so I thought I'd ask for help. I'm trying to pull the text from a txt file and have it output in a .html file but i cant get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>jQuery(function($){
$.get("cheerer.txt", function(txt) {
$('#element-animation').text(txt)
})
})
</script>

<div id="element-animation">
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: you are probably receiving an error. you need to share it too but before you do that let me enlighten you about what the problem probably is: you can not make a script load a local file. browsers forbid it due to security reasons. you need to run a web server. share the error for further help.

Comment: try removing the dollar sign in the param. so `function () {`

Comment: btw, hit F12 to see the error in console.

Comment: It doesn't pull the text even if i try using a .txt from a server. removing the $ didnt do anything. the error i get is Failed to load file:///E:/Shit/TWitchalerts/most_recent_cheerer.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Comment: like the error states, what you try to do is a cross origin request and it is only available to transfer protocols. which summaries to: you need a web server (or an alternate way of whatever you are trying). i'll try to help if you explain what your aim is.

Comment: Im trying to have the .html pull text from a .txt file so I can use it as a browser source in obs studio. The reason I want to do it like this instead of loading up the .txt file in obs is so that i can have more customization/animation over it.

Comment: i dont know what obs studio is but if content of txt file does not change, simply copy paste the text into a javascript string and use it from there. either this or get a simple web browser. like Web Server for Chrome, which is very lite and runs on chrome.

Comment: the txt file does change accordingly so the text is different.

Comment: Then if you use chrome, give Web Server for Chrome a chance. It's easy peasy to use. Host your txt on server then make your $.get call to the txt.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not let you read or modify local resources due to very rightful security reasons.

To read or modify them, you have to host them in a web server.

If you have Chrome on your machine, i can advise you to install the extension **Web Server for Chrome**. It's very easy to use.

Host your txt on server then make your $.get call to the txt url server provides.